# How to set CSS font sizes in contenteditable element?

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

I want to create a small HTML editor with JavaScript where I can set the font-size of the selected text to some specific CSS value. According to the documentation the font size is set with the FontSize command like this:

```
document.execCommand("FontSize", false, x);
```

`x` must be a font size between 1 and 7. The result is that the selected content is wrapped with a `<font size="x" />` element. This isn't very useful because I want to create a drop down box with a lot more font sizes than 7 and I want to use pixels as font size unit so in the end I want the selected text to be wrapped with an element like `<span style="font-size:25px" />`. How do I do that?

I searched for already existing HTML editor components but only found two types of libraries: LARGE things like [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) which are able to do what I want but which are much to large for my purpose and small libraries which only supports these 7 font sizes.

So how can I set custom font-sizes in a contenteditable HTML element? It must work in latest Firefox and Chromium and in IE7-9.

Comment: You'll probably have do do this yourself. Fetch the selected text, delete it, create a new span, put the text in, give the span the desired style, insert the span in the document. By the way, `font-size="25px"` is not a correct attribute. You mean `style="font-size:25px"`, or in js, `theElement.style['fontSize']='25px';`

Comment: @Mr Lister: Was just a brain-typo. Fixed it, thanks for the hint. Doing it manually involves much more than what you describe. The font-size must also be removed from all child elements and the newly introduces span must be merged with the parent element if possible to prevent endless stacking of useless wrapper spans. And then it still is not enough because when you select a whole paragraph then the span is wrapped around block-elements like `p`. So doing this completely manual is very very complicated and I hoped for an easier solution. But I'm afraid there is none...

Comment: Why do you think that the simpler editors don't provide this option and the more complex ones like CKEditor do? Like you said, it's complicated and requires a bunch of code so you can write it or use an existing editor configuring it to your needs and removing non needed parts.

Answer (score 3):

You could try using Rangy for this. It's a cross browser library that tries to eliminate bugs and inconsistencies with ranges/selection in all browsers.
http://code.google.com/p/rangy/

1. get range from selection
2. range.extractContents() and store in var
3. insert a new span node (with id) - range.insertNode(node)
4. jQuery update the new node with step 2 var e.g. $("#spanid").html(docFragment)

See all range methods here:
http://code.google.com/p/rangy/wiki/RangyRange#Methods